# any gae framework that handle file uploads on google-app-engine 

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-upload

which is the best framework  to handle file uploads on gae ,

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a series of posts about how to handle file uploads to the blobstore - here's [the last one](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Implementing-a-dropbox-service-with-the-Blobstore-API-part-3-Multiple-upload-support) (which links to previous ones).

Comment: thanks very much , and which 'full text search' you are using in your site .

Comment: I use a Google Custom Search Engine. How does that relate to this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the blobstore api for handling file uploads.
Refer http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/msg/8798f6f7aa7fc5b7?pli=1
It uses Django on Gae

Answer (score 0):

Try your experience with [http://gaeframework.com](http://www.gaeframework.com)

Comment: You need to disclose your affiliation with products/projects you promote on here.  Please see the policy in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion).